# Python Selenium 2.53.6 hangs while using get() on Firefox 48.0.2

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Exactly what it says on the tin.
Selenium hangs while trying to interact with the latest version of Firefox. I suspect it has something to do with marionette but that level of depth goes over my head. If anyone knows a workaround or fix, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Currently rolling back to Firefox 47 from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox). However, leaving this question open in case anyone knows the fix for myself or others.

Comment: Wrote up an answer providing further instruction based on the ones found there.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no fix for Selenium. Instead, you can use Firefox's Marionette as a replacement.

`pip install marionette_client`

A guide can be found [here](http://marionette-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive.html) for how to use it.

Alternatively, roll back to a previous version of Firefox from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox). This can be a security vulnerability, so transferring over to Marionette is preferable.